# how to fix "no module name mysql"error when connecting python file to mysql database

Tags: python

I try to connect python file to mysql database.when I run my code i got
"No module named mysql" error message

I want to export data from excel file to mysql database using python.

python db_connect.py

Comment: Is the module installed? Else install it. If it is and still the error exists Iike to help.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have that module. You must download it. Type this in cmd:

```
pip install mysql
```